# Synchronize threads in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java

What is the best way to synchronize threads in this case:

```
fun doSomething() {

     readFromDB.subscribe(object : DisposableMaybeObserver<List<Trip>>()) {
         override onSuccess() {
             callback.complete()
         }
         override onFailure() {
             callback.complete()
         }
     }
}
```

Two threads access this block and run into a race condition.
I need only one thread to read from DB and have that state until the callback completes.
How to lock the other thread from executing this block.

Tried using a lock / synchronized. But, how to unlock from within the `onSuccess` or `onFailure`. Does not solve the problem.

In other words, how to wait for the thread to read from DB and get back onSuccess / onFailure, for the 2nd thread to do the same.

Comment: 2 threads are sharing the `callback` instance, right?

Comment: You do not have to synchronize threads in this case its the4 Database method which should be synchronized .

Comment: @dung ya van: The callback instance is shared.

Comment: @ADM : There is some processing needed to be done with the results from the DB and the 2nd thread should not get access to doSomething() until the processing is fully done by the 1st thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could confine the observation to a single-threaded scheduler. Typically, one would need to run completion code on the main thread thus:

```kotlin
readFromDB
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(object : DisposableMaybeObserver<List<Trip>>()) {
    override onSuccess() {
        callback.complete()
    }
    override onFailure() {
        callback.complete()
    }
}
```

If the target thread doesn't matter, you could also use `Schedulers.single()`.